# How can I update apps like Geary to the newest version?

Tags: updates, pantheon-mail

I would like update Geary to the newest version!

Is it possible or is there something special to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest version of Geary is not available for Freya and Ubuntu 14.04, but the developers plan to backport it. See [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1464472) for details.

You can also post a [bounty](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/21620167-backport-latest-geary) for this bug.